# fields with the same name in different tables. how to get a specific one when fetching

Tags: php, mysql

```
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
       $row['fieldName']
   }



$query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
        FROM realestate
        INNER JOIN users ON id_user = users.id
        LEFT JOIN pic ON id_realestate = realestate.id
        {$place}
        {$offer}
        {$type}
        {$price}
        group by realestate.id
        ORDER BY {$order}
        LIMIT 0,10";
```

i have two tables `users` and `realestate`. both have the field `id`. what should be in the fileldname above to get `id` in `users` table?

Comment: Use an alias to assign a unique name to the user id in the mysql select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name the fields in the query: if you do `users.id AS user_id`, then PHP will see a `user_id` field.

Of course, in this particular case it doesn't matter, since you have two equivalent fields: `id_user` and `id_realestate`.

Comment: I think you should be able to just add it to your current query: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROUND_ROWS *, pic.id AS pic_id`

Comment: thank you guys, it actually doesnt matter as u said Borealid, i didnt pay attention to that. anyhow it's a good new piece of info to rename the fields in the query.